# How to split a column by pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column like that, and I want to split it by'-' into two columns, Is there any pandas method to do that? I know I could copy the column and use a regex to do that, I wonder whether there is another way. Thanks:)

```
             Col_A
    0      18K-22K
    1        6K-9K
    2      10K-16K
    3      15K-25K
    4        5K-7K
```

target:

```
        Col_A1 Col_A2
    0      18K    22K
    1       6K     9K
    2      10K    16K
    3      15K    25K
    4       5K     7K
```

Comment: I don't know about the panda but you can write a script, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html):

```
df1 = df['Col_A'].str.split('-', expand=True)
df1.columns = ['Col_A1', 'Col_A2']
print (df1)
  Col_A1 Col_A2
0    18K    22K
1     6K     9K
2    10K    16K
3    15K    25K
4     5K     7K
```

If you want add columns to original `df`:

```
df[['Col_A1', 'Col_A2']] = df['Col_A'].str.split('-', expand=True)
print (df)
     Col_A Col_A1 Col_A2
0  18K-22K    18K    22K
1    6K-9K     6K     9K
2  10K-16K    10K    16K
3  15K-25K    15K    25K
4    5K-7K     5K     7K
```